# Is it possible to fetch ASP.NET or PHP code from a webservers .asp/.aspx/.php files?

Tags: php, asp.net, webserver

Is it possible to fetch ASP.NET or PHP code from a webservers .asp/.aspx/.php files if those files would normally get processed by the ASP or PHP engine?

Comment: You're question is not clear.  If the question is asking if you can run PHP/ASP/ASPX off of a common web server, than yes, that's possible.

Comment: I assume you have a non-illegal reason for asking such a question.

Comment: Is this a security question? Do you want to prevent this from happening or do you want to make it happen?

Comment: This questions is for security purposes - No illegal activity is even considered!
I only asked this question out of curiosity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if accessed via http, and the web server is properly configured.  This would be a HUGE security hole.

If you have physical access to the server, or access via another method, then yes.  If you have a legitimate, legal reason to do so, and you are authorized, the system admin will certainly be able to assist you.

Comment: +1: I thought there was no point repeating what you just said

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me (Retrieving asp/php code through physical access to a server is needless to say, possible)

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of obvious.  ;-)  Sorry for stating something so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have real acces to the server either ftp or anything equivalent to that, or if you take the hard drive out and put it inside your computer :)